# iPhone: white lines in UITableView between nonexistent cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview

[alt text http://img179.imageshack.us/img179/2047/iphonetableview.png](http://img179.imageshack.us/img179/2047/iphonetableview.png)

I have a UITableView within a nib file. It works perfectly with 4 or more cells. When I have only 2 or 3 cells and the screen is not completely filled with cells I have these empty cells (dark gray, which is actually just the background of my TableView) at the bottom.

However, they shouldn't be there, because my `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` returns the correct values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think they are actually cells. You are seeing the white lines because this is the default behavior for the table view. Have you tried changing the separator for the table view to none in IB?

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100513-x5428pkyp8iaqchmkrd41h8m98.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100513-x5428pkyp8iaqchmkrd41h8m98.png)

Comment: That does it, but then all separators are gone, which doesn't really work for my design. Thanks for your suggestion, though.

Comment: I ended up resizing the UITableView every time the data changes. When smaller than screen size I set it to the actual size and when bigger than screen size I set it to screen size and can scroll down.

Answer (score 21):

What you see is the **default behaviour of UITableViewStylePlain**. If you don't want to have "empty cells" below your real cells, move the "More" button (seen in your pic) into UITableView tableFooterView. When you don't have "More" button and still don't want "empty cells", create an empty footer:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

For some reason existance of **tableFooterView removes "empty cells"** after the real cells.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that too. I guess if you don't like it then when you have only 2 or 3 cells, make a 3rd (or 4th) which is blank and non selectable to cover the remainder of the space.

Comment: That's an option. But I was hoping that there is a simple setting which I could change. I don't even understand why it is there. For me this "feature" doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I don't think there is - I think Matt and I have covered the bases :-( I'm going to +1 for Matt - I think the "cleanest" solution would be to follow Matt's guidline then work the separator into your cell design. However, that might give you a last cell or first cell issue (showing a spare separator). But that is still going to be better/easier to solve that than add extra dummy cells as I suggested.